# Custom headers in urlset in Sitemap.xml in nextjs 13.4

Tags: header, sitemap, next.js13, sitemap.xml

I am adding a sitemap to my website, I am adding it in app folder as i am using nextjs 13.4 version. And i need to add custom headers in the urlset tag for adding the specific schema but nextjs seems to generate the tag on its own and i am not able to find any work-around for it.

i nedd to add these but all i am getting is as below:
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"

Can you tell me of a solution for this?

I tried by adding it manually but it didn't work.